# How to know what object is used for sharing in SharePoint online via powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, reports, guid

I have retrieved a report to extract all the site groups across site collections in SharePoint Online tenant.

During this process, I have got an item **"sharing links with GUID"**. how to find what item(document/list item/sub site..) was shared/used with this guid. I am open for powershell or any other mode of retrieval.